# Position of object nouns

Tags: word-order

Welche der folgenden Satzpaare sind grammatisch richtig? Oder sind beide Alternativen korrekt? Die richtige Position von Objekte finde ich sehr verwirrend:

- > Möchten Sie etwas bei mir Essen?
  >   Möchten Sie bei mir etwas Essen?
- > Zuerst können wir im Garten Tee trinken.
  >   Zuerst können wir Tee im Garten trinken.
- > Ich möchte gerne dort ein Stück Kuchen essen.
  >   Ich möchte gerne ein Stück Kuchen dort essen.

Answer (score 8):

Bis auf das großgeschriebene *essen* in den ersten zwei Beispielen sind alle Sätze richtig.

Im Deutschen kann man die Satzstellung zur Hervorhebung eines bestimmten Satzglieds verwenden. Das am meisten hervorgehobene Satzglied steht ganz vorne, das am zweitmeisten hervorgehobene ganz hinten. Danach schwächt sich die Hervorhebung von hinten nach vorne ab.

In einem Fragesatz mit Modalausdruck gehören Ende und Anfang aufgrund der Grammatik zusammen. Ähnlich ist das bei Fragesätzen im Perfekt. Der entscheidende Unterschied in der Hervorhebung liegt also beim *vorletzten Satzglied*:

> **Möchten** Sie etwas *bei mir* **essen**?
>
> **Möchten** Sie bei mir *etwas* **essen**?

Die anderen Beispiele sind keine Fragesätze, so dass dort das erste Satzglied die meiste Hervorhebung erhält und das letzte die zweitmeiste, zusammen mit dem Modalverb. Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen liegt also jeweils beim Satzglied mit der dritthöchsten Hervorhebung, es ist wieder das `vorletzte Satzglied`.

> **Zuerst** *können* wir im Garten `Tee` *trinken*.
>
> **Zuerst** *können* wir Tee `im Garten` *trinken*.
>
> **Ich** *möchte* gerne dort `ein Stück Kuchen` *essen*.
>
> **Ich** *möchte* gerne ein Stück Kuchen `dort` *essen*.

Und so weiter…

> **Ich** *möchte* dort *`gerne`* `ein Stück Kuchen` *essen*.